# Access a TableViewController from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm a beginner in objective-c and want to realize a simple GUI: A `MyMainWindowController` with a corresponding xib wich contains a table and a simple `Add` button.

```
@interface MyMainWindowController : NSWindowController
{
}
@end
```

The implementation code of the controller is nearly empty (pre-defined initWithWindow and windowDidLoad). The `AddressTvc` is defined like this:

```
@interface AddressTvc : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource>
{
  @private
    IBOutlet NSTableView *myTableView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
}
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
@end
```

This works fine. I can click on the `Add` button and a new row is inserted in the table.

[image]

It seems that the `AddressTvc` is created automatically (by the IB?) when the `MyMainWindowController` is visible. I want a reference in the code of `MyMainWindowController` to `AddressTvc` so I'm able to fill the table with some data retrieved by a background thread. This should be done by calling the `- (IBAction)add:(id)sender;` method.

I tried to  create a `AddressTvc` inside the `MyMainWindowController` but then the object is initialized twice. I'm sure I have to wire it somewhere in the IB, but have no clue where to do this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet in you *MyMainWindowController* class that can point to your table view controller class.

E.G.

```
@interface MyMainWindowController : NSWindowController
{
    IBOutlet AddressTvc *myTVC 
}
@end
```

Then simply control+drag from your file owner to the instance of the table view controller in interface builder and you can now access it in your window controllers code.

Comment: So easy ... The bounty was to learn the hard way ;-) Thank you for you help!

Comment: Another question: In `- (void)windowDidLoad` of _MyMainWindowController_ `myTVC` is already initialized (as expected), but otherwise `nil`. How can use the object before I manually open the window?

Comment: Your tvc is contained in the same nib file as your window so both objects are loaded at the same time so the tvc will always be nil until the window has loaded. The alternative is to remove the tvc from your nib file and initialise it in your window controller. You'll have to move all of your outlets and actions to the window controller.